# Streaming QR Code Image into Your ASP.NET Web Pages Using ASP.NET Barcode Generator and click to download

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am Streaming QR Code Image into my ASP.NET Web Pages Using ASP.NET Barcode Generator

```
http://www.onbarcode.com/asp_net/qr-code-generator.html
```

i want to download this image on click of a button.

I have tried javascript but instead downloading the image it is opening in another window.
Also tried changing MIME Types.

P.S: I am not trying to download a saved image.

This is how it is creating a image:
To create barcode image in html or aspx pages, you can insert a image tag (img) into your web pages.
For example, `<img src="http://YourDomain:Port/barcode/qrcode.aspx?DATA=0123456789" />`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the img tag in an anchor i.e.
`<a href="http://YourDomain:Port/barcode/qrcode.aspx?DATA=0123456789"><img src="http://YourDomain:Port/barcode/qrcode.aspx?DATA=0123456789" /></a>`

If the desired effect should be to download the file without user interaction (other than clicking the image) you should create a handler that sets the proper headers on the image response.

This can be done using something like:
Response.Clear();

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.ContentType = "";
Response.End();
```

Comment: then you need to make a handler that can add the proper http header for this.

Comment: I will make a handler , but what should i give type in http header ? MIME TYPE i guess ?

Comment: that should work, that's the way I've done it in previous projects.

Comment: Did you put in the href for the anchor the url to the handler?